# Wifi is not working with some router in ubuntu 14.04, my laptop is lenovo ideapad s510p

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, wireless, networking, lenovo

I bought a **Lenovo ideapad s510p** 3 months back, am facing some wifi issues. While using my laptop in my office with different router, wifi is working fine but when i use it in my home with another router, wifi is showing but it is not getting connected.

Wireless adapter in my laptop is:

**Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter**

Am using Ubuntu 14.04. How to solve this problem please anyone guide me in this.

More info: Wifi router is working fine and getting connected with other laptops in my home.

Comment: Please read this and see if you can include any relevant information to your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the basics first. Make sure the wifi password is correct and that the signal strength is good. 
If you've checked that already, then check if your home wifi router is not using mac filtering. This is a feature, which allows only devices with certain MAC address to connect. If the MAC address of your Lenovo laptop is not in the list, it won't be allowed. 
I can't think of any other reasons really why it might not work, so if the above doesn't work, try resetting the wifi router to factory default settings.